# Usar clase creada en libreria de Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Tengo un proyecto de GAS creado, y necesito usar una clase en él. Dicha clase está creada en una libreria aparte, e importada al proyecto.

El problema está en que no sé como instanciar dicha clase en el proyecto (y que funcione el intellisense del editor de Apps Script).

De momento lo unico que he conseguido es:

Mi clase:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usando la clase:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto funciona correctamente. El problema es que el intellisense apps script no me autocompleta ni me muestra los atributos ni los metodos del objeto coche. Digamos que voy "a ciegas"; y la idea de hacer clases es pasarle dichas bibliotecas a desarrolladores que no van a tener visibilidad del codigo de dichas clases...

¿Existe alguna manera de hacer esto mejor?
Muchisimas gracias por vuestra ayuda!
Un saludo!

Comment: Recién publiqué una respuesta a una pregunta similar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/525403/65

Comment: Gracias Rubén. Entiendo que la respuesta es que no es posible entonces no? Un saludo