# Como puedo acceder a las propiedades y funciones de una clase que ha sido importada como una biblioteca en Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, poo, google-apps-script, clase, instancias

Esta es mi clase "Person".
[image: class Person]

La siguiente imagen muestra lo que quiero conseguir una vez se importe como biblioteca en otro proyecto distinto.
[image: Lo que quiero conseguir en el otro proyecto]

*Ya exporté Person como biblioteca y le di acceso de lectura al otro proyecto para que pudiera usarlo*
Cuando intento usar esta clase como biblioteca importada me pasa esto.
[image: No aparecen las propiedades ni funciones de la clase, pero si funcionan]

Conclusión: Creo instancia del objeto de la biblioteca importada, y no puedo usar sus propiedades o funciones a no ser que sepa lo que hay dentro de la clase.

---

Soluciones que probé también:

1- Añadí la clase "Person" a una variable:

```
var Person = class Person{...
...
...
}
```

2- Añadí una anotación '@constructor' que parece usarse igual que constructor(){}

```
/**
* Person
* @constructor
*/
function(name,surname) {...
...}
```

Comment: Hola, David. Este es un sitio de stackoverflow en español, intenta cambiando de idioma tu pregunta o pregunta en stackoverflow en ingles

Comment: Es correcto, es mi primer post y no sabía que este era en español. Ya cambié el idioma. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualmente el nuevo editor de código de Google Apps Script no soporta esta el autocompletado.

Para tener esta funcionalidad puedes usar otro editor de código. Para pasar el código de un proyecto de apps script puedes usar la API de Google Apps Script, [CLASP](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp), la extensión de Chrome Google Apps Script GitHub Assistant para pasar el código a GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket y quizás otros, entre otras alternativas.

Preguntas relacionadas en SO en inglés

- [How to type hint Google Types in Google Scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64554534/1595451)
- [Apps Script: SubFunctions of my library not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70624789/1595451)